# Very Specific C# to VB.NET Conversion Problem

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am currently working on a project which uses the AutoFac Inversion of Control container.

I am attempting to convert some example code from C# into a codebase of an existing project of mine which is written in VB.NET and I've hit a problem.

The original line of code is:

```
EventHub.Subscribe<HandshakingEvent>(container.Resolve<HandshakeAuthenticator>().CheckHandshake);
```

Which I have converted to:

```
EventHub.Subscribe(Of HandshakingEvent)(Container.Resolve(Of HandshakeAuthenticator)().CheckHandshake)
```

But - this is causing an error, "Argument not specified for parameter 'ev' of CheckHandshake".

The type of the parameter for the *EventHub.Subscribe(Of HandshakingEvent)* procedure is *System.Action (of HandshakingEvent)*

I can see what the problem is, I'm just not really sure what to do about it! I've tried using 'AddressOf', but that doesn't seem to work, either.

Thanks in advance...
- Chris

Comment: What's `CheckHandshake`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
EventHub.Subscribe(Of HandshakingEvent)(AddressOf Container.Resolve(Of HandshakeAuthenticator)().CheckHandshake)
```

(using the `AddressOf` keyword to get a delegate)

Comment: Thanks - You're spot on. I had tried 'AddressOf', but it still didn't work. It turns out it was for a different reason, though! I had declared the parameter of CheckHandshake as ByRef, not ByVal!

Answer (score 3):

The VB code is trying to call the method instead of creating a delegate for it. Use the `AddresOf` operator to get a deletegate:

```
EventHub.Subscribe(Of HandshakingEvent)(AddressOf Container.Resolve(Of HandshakeAuthenticator)().CheckHandshake)
```

The keyword is not needed in C#, as parentheses are always used when you call a method, but in VB you can call a method without parentheses also.

Comment: Thanks - You're spot on. I had tried 'AddressOf', but it still didn't work. It turns out it was for a different reason, though! I had declared the parameter of CheckHandshake as ByRef, not ByVal!